# Фотостена через UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios

Доброго всем времени суток. Возникла проблема в реализации фотостены на ios. Есть сервер откуда приходят данные какие фото/картинки мне грузить в стенку, соответственно стена имеет бесконечную пагинацию пока есть данные. Реализовать стену было не так уж и трудно - фото стена скролится вправо, дойдя до определенной координаты отправляет запрос на новую пачку фото.

Но необходимо сделать поддержку скролинга вниз, а следом и по диагонали и тут возникает проблема в расчете координат ячеек и оптимальном наполнении стены. Пробовал использовать `UICollectionView`, но не смог полностью избавиться пробелов между ячейками(по этому использую `UIScrollView`), что в ходит в одно из требований. [Пример позиций ячеек в стене](http://www.dropbox.com/s/wtdq9t86y7n5v7o/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-03-20%2018.43.16.png)

По возможности, можете кинуть ссылку на решение или подсказать решение. Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте еще поковырять настройки UICollectionView, там задается любой расстояние, к тому же вы можете использовать кастомный layout или стать делегатом существующего UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, все это может вам помочь в решении. В любом случае писать свой грид вью - дело суперответственное и сложное, нужно убдет позаботится о реюзе, работе с памятью и много другом.

Comment: согласен, но нужно обеспечить две степени свободы - скролинг вверх/вниз влево/вправо и  соответственно пагинацию в каждую сторону

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решил своими силами. Базовый алгоритм размещения элементов с примером выложил на [github](https://github.com/Nuclominus/TilesPhotoWall)
Подключил к этому сетевую загрузку и пришла радость ^^
В процессе еще буду дорабатывать, а как же без этого)